# VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract error

Tags: ether, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, chainlink-vrf

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30")


module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const deployer = getNamedAccounts()
  const chainId = network.config.chainId
  let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId


  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    )
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.address

    const transactionResponse = await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
    subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
    await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(
      subscriptionId,
      VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT
    )
  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorv2"]
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
  }


  const enterenceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["enterenceFee"]
  const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
  const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
  const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]

  const arguments = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    enterenceFee,
    gasLane,
    subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit,
    interval,
  ]
  console.log(deployer)

  const lottery = await deploy("Lottery", {
    from: deployer,
    args: arguments,
    log: true,
    waitConformations: network.config.blockConformations || 1,
  })

  if ( !developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    log("Verifying ..........")
    await verify(lottery.address, args)
  }

  log("-----------------------------------")
}


module.exports.tags = ["all", "lottery"]
```

An unexpected error occurred:

```
Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\01-deploy-lottery.js:
TypeError: from.toLowerCase is not a function
    at getFrom (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\helpers.ts:1740:34)
    at _deploy (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\helpers.ts:534:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at _deployOne (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\helpers.ts:1005:16)       
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\01-deploy-lottery.js:50:19)   
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1219:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
```

Can someone help me out with this.. I am having no idea what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is coming b'caz your deployer account is not defined in **hardhat.config.js**. Define it, then deploy the script once again, then it should not come.

> Check the first line of code it is saying from.toLowerCase() is not defined and from the address of deployer. That actually means that deployer is not defined.

Define all the private keys and deployer accounts properly then it should not come. You can take reference from below code:

```js
networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      blockConformations: 1,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true
    },
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [ process.env.PRIVATE_KEY1, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY2],
      chainId: 5,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      blockConformations: 5,
      gas: 5000000,
      gasPrice: 50000000000, 
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true
    },
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
      1: 0,
    },
    player: {
      default: 1,
    },
  },
```

Or from github repo:
https://github.com/Yana-Gupta/hardhat-lottery/blob/main/hardhat.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deploying your contract like this:

```
const lottery = await deploy("Lottery", {
  from: deployer,
  args: arguments,
  log: true,
  waitConformations: network.config.blockConformations || 1,
})
```

try deploying it like this:

```
const Lottery = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lottery")
const lottery = await Lottery.deploy(
  vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
  entranceFee,
  gasLane,
  subscriptionId,
  callbackGasLimit,
  interval
)
```

I had the same issue and this solved it. Newer versions of hardhat recommend it this way, check the docks.

Comment: New method is okay! but old should also work. And at this point, error was not due to old method of deploying contract, it was due to a simple mistake in my **hardhat.config.js** file in which I didn't defined deployer and in deployer script I am using it.